# Convert buffered image to the 2D byte array with the same data

Tags: java, image, image-processing, arrays, bufferedimage

I have written one application for image processing in Java.  I have processed the image which is the buffered image and now I want to return the `byte[]` for that processed image that is I should get the byte array of binarized image.

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[][] binarizeImage(BufferedImage bfImage){

        int red;
        int newPixel;
        int h ;
        int w ;
        int threshold = otsuTreshold(bfImage);   
          // this function returns the threshold value 199

        BufferedImage binarized = new BufferedImage(bfImage.getWidth(), bfImage.getHeight(), bfImage.getType());

        for(int i=0; i<bfImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<bfImage.getHeight(); j++) {

            // Get pixels
            red = new Color(bfImage.getRGB(i, j)).getRed();
            int alpha = new Color(bfImage.getRGB(i, j)).getAlpha();
            if(red > threshold) {
                newPixel = 255;
            }
            else {
                newPixel = 0;
            }
            newPixel = colorToRGB(alpha, newPixel, newPixel, newPixel);
            binarized.setRGB(i, j, newPixel); 
       }

     }
          Raster raster  = binarized.getData();

    h = raster.getHeight();
    w = raster.getWidth();

    byte[][] binarize_image = new byte[w][h];

    for(int i=0 ; i<w ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<h ; j++)
        {
            binarize_image[i][j]=raster.getSampleModel();  //error at this line 
        }
   }
   return binarize_image;
}

// Convert R, G, B, Alpha to standard 8 bit
    private static int colorToRGB(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {

        int newPixel = 0;
        newPixel += alpha;
        newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += red; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += green; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += blue;

        return newPixel;

    }
```

But it is not working. What should I do to convert that buffered image to byte array for the same image data?

Comment: What would you like `binarize_image` to contain after conversion? 8 bit black/white + 8 bit alpha per pixel? If so, how do you expect to store this in 8 bits per pixel? This is not really what I think of as binary, but you are perhaps creating an artistic effect? In any case, you can probably get away without the temporary `binarized` image, and just set values directly to `binarize_image` in the first loop.

Comment: The main aim behind writing the code is to just want to convert the gray image to the binarized image.And i am trying with above code.

Comment: What is a "binarized" image? Do you mean binary, as in black/white only? Is your input image always gray? 8 bit?

Comment: yes binarized image means black and white image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the term "binarize" means at this context. You seem to just want to filter the image (i.e. cutt-off the red channel based on some threshold) and convert the result to a `byte[]`.

Assuming the above is correct then check the code below. It will convert the image to a `byte[]` for a 32-bit image. Please take into account the following:

- You do not need to first filter the image and then convert to `byte[]`. You can do that during the conversion.
- *"Convert RGB to standard 8-bit"* : If you mean 8-bit **per color channel** then this is ok, but if you mean 8-bit **per pixel** then you are talking about compression/conversion (i.e. you will probably loose some information/quality) in which case you should provide more information about what you want to achieve.
- Your resulting `byte[]` would have a size of `4 * width * height` not `width * height` assuming we are talking about the case of a 32-bit image. If you need to handle other cases you should take into account the available image types supported by the `BufferedImage` (or at least only the ones you are interested in).

The code below will print information for each converted pixel like below (Note how the red channel is filtered):

`[0,0] Converting [ffaaccee] --> [0, cc, ee, ff]`

```
package imageio.byteconversion;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageToBytes {

    private static void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    private static String toByteString(int color) {
        // Perform a bitwise AND for convenience while printing. 
        // Otherwise Integer.toHexString() interprets values as integers and a negative byte 0xFF will be printed as "ffffffff"
        return Integer.toHexString(color & 0xFF);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Load the image. This expects the image to be in the same package with this class 
        InputStream stream = BufferedImageToBytes.class.getResourceAsStream("test.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
        int iw = image.getWidth();
        int ih = image.getHeight();
        log("Image loaded succesfully, width=" + iw + " height=" + ih);
        stream.close();

        log("Image color model: " + image.getColorModel());
        log("Image sample model: " + image.getSampleModel());
        log("Image raster: " + image.getRaster());

        int bands = image.getSampleModel().getNumBands();
        log("Color bands: " + bands);
        if (bands != 4) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The image does not have 4 color bands. Are you sure this is a 32-bit image?");
        }

        int threshold = 199; // <-- decide your threshold here

        byte bytes[] = new byte[4 * iw * ih];
        int index = 0;

        // note that image is processed row by row top to bottom
        for(int y = 0; y < ih; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < iw; x++) {

                // returns a packed pixel where each byte is a color channel
                // order is the default ARGB color model
                int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);

                // Get pixels
                int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
                int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
                int blue = pixel & 0xFF;

                // perform filtering here depending on threshold 
                if (red > threshold) {
                   red = 255;
                } else {
                    red = 0;
                }

                log("[" + x + "," + y + "]" + " Converting [" + Integer.toHexString(pixel)  + "] --> ["
                        + toByteString(red) + ", " + toByteString(green) + ", " 
                        + toByteString(blue) + ", " + toByteString(alpha)
                        + "]");

                bytes[index++] = (byte) red;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) green;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) blue;
                bytes[index++] = (byte) alpha;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I just want to binarize the gray image so the above code is for that.

Comment: @rachana What do you mean by _"binarize"_? Convert to `byte[]`? If yes then the above code will work (though you could probably save more space) just remove the check that throws the exception. Do you want to convert it to a gray image? Please clarify what image do you use for source and what is your desired output

Comment: Binarize image means i want to convert the gray image into black and white format and that's what i am trying to do with that code and also after binarization i want to convert the binarized buffered image to byte array as other operations to process the image requires byte array.

Comment: If you know about any algorithm for image binarization please let me know.

Comment: @rachana I am still not sure what you are asking. An algorithm or convert to `byte[]`? For an algorithm you already have it. Your code should convert the image to black and white. For converting to `byte[]` I have given you code that converts an image to `byte[]`. So what exactly is the problem? You can pass your `binarized` variable to my code instead load a new file

Comment: Yes I am completely ok with your code sir and my one issue is now get solved to get byte array.Now I just want to clear my main aim which is to get binarized image i.e in black and white format.

Comment: @rachana if this is the case then ok. Just a note for your conversion: if your image is already in gray scale you might achieve better results if your threshold is 128 (i.e. half of the 255). 199 will just make white all the light areas while converting to completely black all the rest. It depends on the image I guess

Comment: Yes it depends on image.Can you please suggest me any algorithm to binarized the image?

Comment: @rachana check [this link](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html). It has a java demo that might fit your case

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
BufferedImage input;

BufferedImage binary = new BufferedImage(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

Graphics2D g = binary.createGraphics();
try {
    g.drawImage(input, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
   g.dispose();
}
```

It will not use your `otsuTreshold`, and it will (probably) dither the image, but it will do the job of making it binary (black/white only), using a minimal amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
  try {
                  // get the BufferedImage, using the ImageIO class
                  Bitmap image = 
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets()
                            .open("aa.bmp"));
                  marchThroughImage(image);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    });


}
public void printPixelARGB(int pixel) {
    int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
    int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
    System.out.println("argb: " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
  }
private void marchThroughImage(Bitmap image) {
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    System.out.println("width, height: " + w + ", " + h);

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        System.out.println("x,y: " + j + ", " + i);
        int pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        printPixelARGB(pixel);
        System.out.println("");
      }
    }
  }
```